# Samba como controlador de dominio

Tags: ubuntu, samba

necesito ayuda para que samba sea controlador de dominio y que haga uso de Bind9, antes hice que samba sea controlador de dominio y todo salió bien pero el fallo lo tengo en que si hago un host -t SRV _ldap.tcp.dominio.es, sale el error NXDOMAIN. Configuré el hostname y el archivo hosts correctamente, pero no sé que tengo que hacer con bind9 para que funcione junto a samba. ¿Alguien me puede ayduar explicandomelo o con una guía?

PD: He buscado por Internet pero nada me a ayudado

Comment: podrias describir el error? agregando a tu pregunta!

Comment: El error es NXDOMAIN cuando hago un host -t SRV _ldap.tcp.dominio.es después de hacer que samba sea controlador de dominio, a parte de eso no sé nada más

Comment: el comando no es host -T?  lo estas haciendo desde el mismo servidor o desde uno remoto! es que la pregunta esta demaciado global como para tener una idea clara de cual puede ser el error!

Comment: Desde el mismo servidor, y en las guías que he visto es host -t (minúscula)

Comment: podrias darle un `traceroute` ldap.tcp.dominio.es a ver que te devuelve!